# "Eigenvalue" has a "trivial eigenvector"

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We have a matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -2 & 0\\
 a & 4 & 0\\
  0&  b  &  c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
One of the eigenvalues of this matrix should be $1$.

However if I try the following:

$$(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0\\
a & 4 & 0\\
0&  b  &  c
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0&  0  &  1
\end{bmatrix})\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

As you can see in the Gaussian elimination we can "destroy" the whole middle column with the top middle element, and then we are able to get the matrix into row echelon form.

I get a trivial solution (so that $x,y,z = 0$), however my question is, are the solutions wrong about this eigenvalue for such matrix?

Comment: Are you asked to figure out which values of $a,b,c$ are needed to make $1$ into an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that is the question

Answer (score 2):

After you "destroy" the middle column and swap the first two rows you end up with $\begin{bmatrix}a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c-1\end{bmatrix}$. You only have a trivial solution if $a\neq 0$ and $c-1\neq 0$. If $a=0$ or $c=1$ you have nontrivial solutions.

Comment: I see, because then I cannot divide by zero to get it into row echelon form

Answer (score 0):

If I expand out the determinant for $A-\lambda I$, I get

$$\lambda^3 -(5+c)\lambda^2 + (5c+2a+ 4)\lambda - (2ac + 4c)$$

If I divide this polynomial by $\lambda-1$, as required, I get by synthetic division:
$$ \lambda^2 -(c+4)\lambda +2a + 4c$$ and the requirement that $-2a(c-1) = 0$, which implies either $c=1$ or $a = 0$.

Also, remember that $(0,0,0)$ is a trivial eigenvector for any number as eigenvalue, which is why we exclude it.  We care about nonzero eigenvectors, which is more interesting, so I think being nonzero is part of the definition of the eigenvector.

Comment: if $\lambda=1$ should be a root of the polynomial, you can just plug in $\lambda=1$ and set the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ to $0$